# Pinescript Strategy exit and order Quantity calculations

Tags: pine-script

Is there any reading you recommend about the following issue? I still did not find an answer to it

strategy.exit (or also strategy.order) parameter "qty". I am passing qty as 25% of the initial position size.

Example: position size is 11, then exit qty is 2.75.
After 4 times (4 orders triggered) it should be completely out (meaning exited the full position).
Strategy backtest is taking only -2 out each time. Leaving positionsize higher than 0 after 4 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a minimum position size associated with each market. The value isn't visible to scripts or through the charts UI, but the broker emulator uses it in strategies. Your market may not allow fractional position sizes.